# React autoscrolling

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to implement lazy loading of the product list. I've simulated asynchronous request to server. The user should be able to update the page by scrolling even if items ended.
The problem is when the loading  element disappears it executes handleScroll() handler because the height of the page changes and infinite loop starts. But I want to execute handleScroll() only if the user scrolls the page.
Here is the code of my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './items-list.css';

import ItemsListItem from './items-list-item.jsx';

export default class ItemsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        categoryId: this.props.categoryId,
        items: [],
        isLoading: true
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll());
      this.simulateAsyncGetItems(10);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll());
    }

    simulateAsyncGetItems(n){//TODO: delete in prod
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        let res = this.getItems(this.props.categoryId, n, this.state.items.length);
        this.setState({
          items: [...this.state.items, ...res],
          isLoading: false
        });
      }, 1000);
    }

    getItems(categoryId, limit, offset){
      //TODO: implement request to fetch data from server
      if(offset >= 20) {
        return []
      }
      return categoryId === -1 ? [] : new Array(limit).fill(
        {
          id: 12345678,
          categoryId: categoryId,
          name: "Product name might be long",
          img: "boat.jpg",
          price: 1111.11
        });//dummy
    }

    handleScroll(){
      return (event) => {
        let relativeScrollOffset = //scroll offset from 0.0 to 1.0
          event.srcElement.scrollingElement.scrollTop /
          (event.srcElement.scrollingElement.scrollHeight - event.srcElement.scrollingElement.clientHeight);
        if (!this.state.isLoading && !this.state.noMoreData && relativeScrollOffset >= 0.9)
          this.simulateAsyncGetItems(5);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div className="items-list" >
          {(this.state.items && Array.isArray(this.state.items)) && this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
            <ItemsListItem
                id={item.id}
                img={item.img}
                name={item.name}
                price={item.price}
                key={i}
              />
          )}
          {this.state.isLoading&&
            <div>
              Data is loading, please wait...
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem and just set fixed height for  element that is empty when nothing is loading